# Living within my numproc barrier

Tags: centos, java, openfire

So I pay around $50/month for a 2GB VPS which has 200 numproc limit. I have no idea if that is good or bad... and I'm not amazingly technical.

I have always had a stable VPS running a couple of VOIP servers, some forums and other various non-profit websites/tools. Then I installed openfire XMPP server...

This server spawns about 140 java threads under a single process which is killing my numprod limit. Any ideas as to how I can reduce the number of threads?

The process is:
`/opt/openfire/jre/bin/java -server -Xms128m -Xmx256m -DopenfireHome=/opt/openfire -Dopenfire.lib.dir=/opt/openfire/lib -classpath /opt/openfire/lib/startup.jar -jar /opt/openfire/lib/startup.jar`

Thanks

Comment: some promising flags here - http://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-1061 , specifically xmpp.server.outgoing.threads and xmpp.server.processing.threads

Comment: Interesting. After looking at settings like 'xmpp.processor.count' I checked and I have 144 cores available to my VPS which is roughly the amount of threads I have.

`xmpp.processor.count
the number of threads (-1) in the pool to accept socket connections
DEFAULT = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() (the number of processors available to the JVM, int)`

Comment: @radai Could you write that up in an Answer please? Thank you!

Comment: @ChrisS - yeah sure. personally i think its low quality though :-)

Answer (score 1):

some promising flags [here](http://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-1061), specifically `xmpp.server.outgoing.threads` and `xmpp.server.processing.threads`. The default sets the number of threads to the number of processors in the machine.